# finding the first value of last streak in a column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1]})
```

And this is the outcome that I want:

```
    a    b
0   1  NaN
1   0  NaN
2   0  NaN
3   1  NaN
4   0  NaN
5  -1  NaN
6  -1  NaN
7  -1  NaN
8   0  NaN
9  -1  x
10 -1  NaN
11 -1  NaN
```

I want to find the last streak of numbers. In my sample it is -1 and then mark the first value of that streak. I want to have four additional conditions:

a) I dont want streak if it is streak of 0s.

b) The streak must be at least two rows.

c) If the last streak is 0, I don't want to mark anything. like the column `E` in the image below.

d) Note that in column `F` of the image I also don't want to mark anything.

To clarify more, in this image I highlighted the row that I want with different samples. Each column represent a unique sample like the above example. If there are no highlights, then no row should be marked.

[image]

And this is what I have tried but did not work:

```
mask = (df.a == -1)
df.loc[(mask.cumsum() == mask.sum() - 1) & mask, 'b'] = 'x'
```

And after finding the row, what is the best way to get that row without creating a new column like I did here?

I have a tendency to create a new column and then get the rows that the value is not `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
grp = df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum()
cond1 = df.index == grp.idxmax()
cond2 = grp.groupby(grp).transform('count').gt(1)
df.loc[cond1 & cond2 & df['a'].ne(0), 'b'] = 'x'
```

df:

```
    a   b
0   1   NaN
1   0   NaN
2   0   NaN
3   1   NaN
4   0   NaN
5   -1  NaN
6   -1  NaN
7   -1  NaN
8   0   NaN
9   -1  x
10  -1  NaN
11  -1  NaN
```

if you want get row directly, use following code

```
out = df.loc[cond1 & cond2 & df['a'].ne(0)]
```

out :

```
     a
9   -1
```

---

**Intermideate**

chk `grp` with `df`

```
df              grp

    a           
0   1           1
1   0           2
2   0           2
3   1           3
4   0           4
5   -1          5
6   -1          5
7   -1          5
8   0           6
9   -1          7  <-- idxmax
10  -1          7
11  -1          7
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution does not work with this condition. `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0]})` If the last streak is 0 I don't want to mark anything.

Comment: @Amir If you have any desired conditions, you must clearly indicate them in the question.

Comment: I already gave you a thumbs up. I edited my question.

Comment: @Amir I modify the code with given condition.

Comment: I am so sorry. If df is `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0]})`. It does not work either. It is completely my fault. I thought since I said it needs to be the last streak. It is clear.

Comment: @Amir I modify the code with given condition,again. It feels like I was given a free-of-charge request, not a question. you can solve any additional conditions by yourself.

Comment: I must think of these before. I thought "last streak" means the last streak. But it feels like it was not that clear. My bad